# Missing right parenthesis oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got the following query which is telling me missing right parenthesis. The inner subquery without the first select and listagg works perfectly but when I add

```
   SELECT audit_date, charge_type, customer_no, nam, result, 
   LISTAGG(charge_type, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY charge_type desc) charge_name
```

It's telling me - missing right parenthesis although I see no error.

Query:

```
  SELECT audit_date, charge_type, customer_no, nam, result, 
  LISTAGG(charge_type, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY charge_type desc) charge_name
 FROM
     (
      SELECT audit_date, charge_type, customer_no, name nam, sum(amount) result
      FROM
         ( 
          select 
           CASE 
            WHEN i.charge_type = 'GSMUsageCharge' THEN 'GSMUsageCharge'
            ELSE i.charge_type
            END charge_type,
           CASE 
            WHEN i.charge_type='GSMUsageCharge' AND cp.name='Service Charges' THEN 'Call Charges'
            ELSE cp.name
           END name,
       i.amount amount, s.audit_date, cu.customer_no, g.mobile_no
      from charge.gp_schedule gp, charge.gsm_charge_plan cp, ledger.sales_audit s,  
      ledger.invoice_item i, service.gsm g, service.contract c, 
      ccare.customer cu, charge.gsm_fixed_charge gfc
      where s.code = i.sales_audit_code
      and i.charge_plan_code = gp.charge_plan_code
      and gp.charge_plan_code = cp.code
      and cp.service_code = g.code
      and g.contract_code = c.contract_no
      and c.customer_code = cu.customer_no
      and gfc.code(+) = gp.charge_code
      and s.type_code = 'IR'
     ) modified_names
   group by audit_date, customer_no, charge_type, name;
 ) res
 GROUP BY audit_date, charge_type, customer_no, nam, result;
```

Comment: There is still a semicolon after `name`, which ends the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
group by audit_date, customer_no, charge_type, name;
```

The semicolon ends the query string.  Just remove it.